# RMI Exception: proxy cannot be cast to remote object

Tags: java, rmi

I'm getting the above error when trying to view the attributes of a remote object on the client side. After reading a post on a forum (http://www.java-forums.org/networking/69581-rmi-classcastexception-proxy-cannot-cast.html) I thought this happened because of the remote object being in different package names in the client and the server, so I moved the client program (and even the remote interface) in the same package with the server and the remote object itself. But I still have the same error:

> Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ClassCastException: com.sun.proxy.$Proxy0 cannot be cast to uk.ac.rm950.nonPublicDataSerializationServer.Employee
>   at uk.ac.rm950.nonPublicDataSerializationServer.ClientSideProgram.main(ClientSideProgram.java:26)

This is my remote interface:

```
package uk.ac.rm950.nonPublicDataSerializationServer;

public interface ObjectTransporter<T> extends java.rmi.Remote {
public T fetchObject() throws java.rmi.RemoteException;
}
```

The remote object class looks like this:

```
package uk.ac.rm950.nonPublicDataSerializationServer;

import java.rmi.RemoteException;

//import uk.ac.rm950.remoteInterface.ObjectTransporter;

public class Employee implements ObjectTransporter<Employee> {

public String name;

public Employee(String name) {
this.name = name;
}

@Override
public Employee fetchObject() throws RemoteException {
return this;
}
}
```

This is the server program:

```
package uk.ac.rm950.nonPublicDataSerializationServer;

import java.rmi.registry.Registry;
import java.rmi.server.UnicastRemoteObject;

//import uk.ac.rm950.remoteInterface.ObjectTransporter;

public class ServerSideProgram {

public static void main(String[] args) {
System.setProperty("java.security.policy", "security/server.policy");

if (System.getSecurityManager() == null) {
System.setSecurityManager(new SecurityManager());
}

try {
Registry registry = LocateRegistry.createRegistry(1099);

ObjectTransporter<Employee> transportingObject = new Employee("Nemo");
ObjectTransporter<Employee> stub = (ObjectTransporter<Employee>) UnicastRemoteObject.exportObject(transportingObject, 0);
registry.rebind("employee", stub);

System.out.println("Employee object bound.");
} catch (RemoteException e) {
System.out.println("Exception occurred on server side.");
e.printStackTrace();
}}}
```

This is the client-side code:

```
 package uk.ac.rm950.nonPublicDataSerializationServer;

 import java.rmi.NotBoundException;
 import java.rmi.RemoteException;
 import java.rmi.registry.LocateRegistry;
 import java.rmi.registry.Registry;

 //import uk.ac.rm950.remoteInterface.ObjectTransporter;

 public class ClientSideProgram {

 public static void main(String[] args) {
 System.setProperty("java.security.policy", "security/server.policy");

 if (System.getSecurityManager() == null) {
 System.setSecurityManager(new SecurityManager());
 }

 try {
 Registry registry = LocateRegistry.getRegistry();
 ObjectTransporter<Employee> transportedObject = (ObjectTransporter<Employee>) registry.lookup("employee");

 //  Employee deserializedEmployee = (Employee) transportedObject.fetchObject();
 System.out.println(transportedObject.fetchObject().name);  
 } catch (RemoteException e) {
 e.printStackTrace();
 } catch (NotBoundException e) {
 e.printStackTrace();
 }}}
```

The error is thrown as the client program is executed, I can't figure out what I'm doing wrong.

Comment: have you compiled your stub/skeleton using RMIC?

Comment: I don't think you have to use RMIC in java version higher than 1.5.

Comment: @TMcKeown Failing to do that wouldn't cause this problem.

Answer (score 1):

You're trying to cast the stub to the remote object itself. You can't. It isn't. You should be casting it to the remote interface:

```
ObjectTransporter<Employee>
```

Comment: first of all thanks very much for answering. My apologies for not getting your point. I thought I am casting the stub, i.e. registry.lookup("employee"), to the remote interface, i.e. ObjectTransporter<Employee> on line:
ObjectTransporter<Employee> transportedObject = (ObjectTransporter<Employee>) registry.lookup("employee");

Thereafter, I'm trying to fetch the remote object, i.e. Employee, and inspect the name attribute on that object. transportedObject.fetchObject() should return an Employee object which is what I need, but it's on this line that the exception is thrown.

Comment: It can't return an Employee object. It can only return an ObjectTransporter<Employee>. Your remote interface definition is wrong. Remote objects don't get transported. They stay where they are, and are replaced by their stubs during Serialization.

Comment: If I may ask, in this case what should I do to send a copy of my remote object to the client?

Comment: You can't. It's a remote object. Make up your mind about it. Either you want to copy it or you want it to be a remote object. Not both at the same time. You have a serious design-time confusion here.